# CSS, UL menu with pop-up LI elements that appear over upper banner

Tags: css, html, menu, popup

I'm trying to create a CSS based menu for a site I'm creating, and not having much luck. Below you can see an image that shows what it is that I'm trying to achieve (the entire menu and header are in one block):

[image: Menu layout example]

The upper half of the screen which is shown in a steel-blue colour in the image, will have contained in it, a div with a background image, and a heading one tag positioned absolutley to place the text over the top of the image.

The part below that, shown in an off-yellow colour in the example image, is a standard un-ordered list element containing normal li list tags.

Something like the following:

```
<ul>
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>Page 1</li>
  <li>Page 2</li>
  <li>Page 3</li>
</ul>
```

Each of the list elements in the unordered list parent container will contain an anchor tag along the lines of:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="page1">Page 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="page2">Page 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="page3">Page 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

When a list item containing an anchor, has a href that matches the actual page being viewed, the intention is that it's height get's increased, such so that it grows outside of the un-ordered list parent that contains it.  In doing this it overlays the steel-blue area of the parent page, something similar to the bright purple rectangle in the example image.

A list item that is not matched, and not hovered, shown as blue rectangles in the example image, should remain inside the parent unordered list and with its default background styling and colours.

When a list item is hovered, it should change to a style that is the same as one that is matched to the page, height wise, and be outside the parent list, but it should take on a different colour to show that it's hovered and not matched, and it should return to it's previous state (The blue rectangles) after the hover is finished.

I sort of have things partially working, this is how it currently looks:

[image: Menu as is currently working]

As you can see, the actual unordered list element will not flow down and each of the list items inside of it overlap each other, I suspect this is because I have each list item set up with absolute positioning.

If I change the list items so they use relative positioning, it solves the overlap issue, however that prevents the list items from popping up over the top of the parent list element and overlaying the steel-blue section of the image.

There is also one other complication. I have very little control of the generated mark-up as this is being produced by a CMS (mojoPortal to be exact). The mark-up that is being generated by ASP.NET is currently as follows:

```
<nav class="span12" id="ctl00_SiteMenu1_ctl00">
  <ul id="ctl00_SiteMenu1_ctl00_UL" class="root-nav">
    <li class="current">
  <a href="/home.aspx">Home</a>
    </li>
<li>
      <a href="/contact-us.aspx">Contact Us</a>
    </li>
<li>
      <a href="/new-page.aspx">Frogs</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I know that the classes `root-nav` and `current` are defined elsewhere, and I do have the ability to override ANY CSS rules existing with any of my own.

The example above with the overlapping, this is defined as follows:

```
.mainhead
{
  background: url(img/menu-banner.png);
  height: 170px;
}

ul.root-nav
{
  background: #B3A90E;
  border-radius: 0px;
  z-index: 1000;
  position: relative;
  width: 1170px;
}

ul.root-nav li.current > a
{
  background-color: #B30D9E;
  background-image: none;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 1010;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -30px;
  border-radius: 25px 25px 0px 0px;
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
}

ul.root-nav li > a
{
  background-color: #1C10B3;
  background-image: none;
  z-index: 1010;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -30px;
  border-radius: 25px 25px 0px 0px;
  width: 100px;
}

ul.root-nav li > a:hover
{
  background-color: #0BB312;
  background-image: none;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 1010;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -30px;
  border-radius: 25px 25px 0px 0px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

I'd like to get this working with the overlay, instead of my alternitive, which is to make the yellow area the maximum height I expect any of the pop-up items to be and fix it in place so nothing moves when heights change.

I'm doing this in HTML5 so HTML5 markup and CSS rules are perfectly fine.

Thanks in advance for any ideas anyone comes up with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

and in about an hour... I'm back.

and here's something that definitely should be a top question on stack overflow...

WHY? when ever you post a question on stack overflow do you usually end up solving it yourself, in a pretty short time afterwards.

Anyway, enough of that.

The reason I was getting the overlap I was getting above was beacuse I wasn't setting the LI sizes.

Simply adding the following rules:

```
ul.root-nav li.current
{
  min-width: 100px;
}

ul.root-nav li
{
  min-width: 100px;
}
```

to my stylsheet, just before **ul.root-nav li-current > a** resolved my issue.

I was correct about my thoughts on the height not being set for the UL due to the absolute positioning, but setting a fixed height on that did the trick.

Comment: Maybe you could delete your questions .. and your answer. héhé .. but you're right .. "when ever you post a question on stack overflow do you usually end up solving it yourself, in a pretty short time afterwards."

Comment: :-) crazy ain't it, I think it must have something to do with the alternative thought process when posting, I find that I think about things in a different way when composing the post, than I do when writing code.  Maybe this switch triggers something sub-consciously, which then leads to a resolution.  A subject I feel would be very interesting to explore some time.

Comment: +1 for admitting that some of us do not think before asking for help.

Comment: Looking back on this answer 6 years later (in 2019) I now know WHY this actually happens. It's been scientifically proven that talking yourself through a problem, often triggers your sub-consiousnes to take divergent paths that you normally wouldn't use.  There is actually a recommended approach to using it effectively now called "Rubber Duck Thinking", the idea being that you have some inanimate object in your workspace that you talk to and tell about your problem.  In my case it's a "Telerik Ninja" (https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a9/fe/9a/a9fe9a775ff36be23681854933393d25.jpg) :-)